# rolling cumulative sums conditional on missing data

Tags: r, data.table, cumulative-sum

I want to calculate rolling cumulative sums by item in a data.table.  Sometimes, data is missing for a given time period.

```
set.seed(8)
item <- c(rep("A",4), rep("B",3))
time <- c(1,2,3,4,1,3,4)
sales <- rpois(7,5)
DT <-  data.table(item, time,sales)
```

For a rolling window of 2 time periods I want the following output:

```
   item time sales sales_rolling2
1:    A    1     5              5
2:    A    2     3              8
3:    A    3     7             10
4:    A    4     6             13
5:    B    1     4              4
6:    B    3     6              6
7:    B    4     4             10
```

Note, that item B has no data at time 2.  Thus the result for row 6 just includes the latest observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rollsum` from `library(zoo)` to do the rolling sum.  Before applying the `rollsum`, I guess we need to create another grouping variable ('indx') based on the 'time' variable.  I find that for the item 'B', the time is not continous, ie. 2 is missing.  So, we can use `diff` to create a logical index based on the difference of adjacent elements.  If the difference is not 1, it will return TRUE or else FALSE.  As the `diff` output is of `length` 1 less than the `length` of the column, we can pad with `TRUE` and then do the `cumsum` to create the 'indx' variable.

```
library(zoo)
DT[, indx:=cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(time)!=1))]
```

In the second step, we use both 'indx' and 'time' as the grouping variable, get the `rollsum` of 'sales' with `k=2` and also based on the condition that if the number of elements in the group is greater than 1 only we need to do this (`if(.N >1)`), otherwise it should return the 'sales', create the 'sales_rolling2', and assign (`:=`) the 'indx' to NULL as it is not needed in the expected output.

```
DT[, sales_rolling2 := if(.N>1) c(sales[1],rollsum(sales,2)) else sales,
               by = .(indx, item)][,indx:= NULL]
#   item time sales sales_rolling2
#1:    A    1     5              5
#2:    A    2     3              8
#3:    A    3     7             10
#4:    A    4     6             13
#5:    B    1     4              4
#6:    B    3     6              6
#7:    B    4     4             10
```

#### Update

As per @Khashaa's suggestion, we can use `roll_sum` from `library(RcppRoll)` can be used more effectively as it will even work with number of rows less than 'k'.  In this way, we can remove the `if/else` condition in my previous solution.  (Full credit to @Khashaa)

```
library(RcppRoll)
DT[, sales_rolling2 := c(sales[1L], roll_sum(sales, 2)), by = .(indx, item)]
```

Comment: This works, but how would I extend it to wider windows?  For example, a rolling window of 3 time periods.

Comment: @lever Just change `k` value i.e. `k=3`

Comment: @lever I guess it is due to the number of rows are less than 3.  So instead of `if(.N>1)` , may be you can use `if(.N>3)` or so.

Comment: @akrun `RcppRoll` works (i.e returns `NA`) when the number of rows is smaller than the window size.

Comment: @Khashaa I don't know much about RcppRoll.  Feel free to post as a solution if you want.  Thanks for the comments

Comment: @akrun `RcppRoll::roll_sum` in a place of `zoo::rollsum`

Comment: @Khashaa Can I add that in the post